# avoiding many if statements, code improvement

Tags: java, design-patterns, spring-security

I have oracle database that I can't change. In this db I have a user table with authority fields.

```
CREATE TABLE USER (
    ID NUMBER(38,0), 
    LOGIN VARCHAR2(6 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    PASSWORD VARCHAR2(200 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 

    BOOK_READ NUMBER(1,0), 
    BOOK_UPD NUMBER(1,0), 
    R_READ NUMBER(1,0), 
    R_UPD NUMBER(1,0), 
    ... 
    ...
)
```

For example:

```
book_read = 1;  - means that user has authority 
book_upd  = 0;  - means that user he does not
report_read = 1;
```

Right now I am checking like this:

```
List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
if (user.getBook_read() == 1) {
    authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_BOOK_READ"));
}
if (user.getBook_upd() == 1) {
    authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_BOOK_UPD"));
}
if (user.getReport_read() == 1) {
    authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_REPORT_READ"));
}
```

I have a lot of Authorities (about 20, they all have a separate column in the table). Сan someone suggest how I can improve the code?

Comment: I think this belongs to code review, but be sure to check the [migration checklist](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1689/150216)

Comment: try switch statement

Comment: What does *"I have a lot of Authorities"* mean? How many? How are they stored? Are they all individual columns in a `USER` table? If you want help to improve the code, you at least need to give us more relevant information.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Funny! If an "authority" is a right to do something, and I "have a lot of them", then I must be nearing godhood.

Comment: So, 20 separate boolean-style (numeric 1 = true) "authority" columns in the database. What is field `user`? And how are you reading the "authority" columns into that object *(plain JDBC? ORM? Which one?)*? Code improvement should probably start there, so don't you think that would be relevant information for us helping with your question?

Comment: You lack a mapping between these values and their respective roles.  If you had a way of mapping the value of book_read to ROLE_BOOK_READ, you could effectively assign permissions for any and all permissions without listing them all.  Consider using a Map<String, Boolean> where the key is the role and the value is whether permission is assigned.  With this map, you should be able to do what you're already doing in a generic fashion using only a loop.

Comment: @Andreas user is a table. i am using spring jdbc templates

Comment: And *how* are you using the spring jdbc templates? Come on, stop giving incomplete information. Getting tired of pulling relevant information out of you. E.g. are you using a `RowMapper`? Are you getting a list of maps? Spring jdbc templates supports more than one way of doing things.

Comment: @Andreas yes RowMapper, but all this not my code and I cant edit it. So basicly it doent matter . I have User class that same as User table. And I have to work with the fact that there is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that right now you have 20 authority *columns* in the database, and a `User` Model object with 20 *fields*, 20 *getters*, and 20 *setter*, and you need 20 `if` statements to build the `List<GrantedAuthority>`.

To simplify that, I'd suggest starting with the Model object and the DAO.

For improved flexibility, create an `enum` with the 20 authorities, and explicitly name the database column name and the Role name, e.g.

```
public enum User_Authority {
    BOOK_READ("BOOK_READ", "ROLE_BOOK_READ"),
    BOOK_UPD ("BOOK_UPD" , "ROLE_BOOK_UPD"),
    // more enums

    // fields here

    private User_Authority(String columnName, String roleName) {
        // assign to fields here
    }

    // getters here
}
```

Your `User` Model object can then use an `EnumSet<User_Authority>` to store which authorities are granted to the user.

Your Spring JDBC Template can then use a [`RowMapper`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowMapper.html) with logic like this:

```
public final class UserRowMapper implements RowMapper<User> {
    @Override
    public User mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) {
        User user = new User();
        // get other columns here
        EnumSet<User_Authority> granted = EnumSet.noneOf(User_Authority.class);
        for (User_Authority auth : User_Authority.values())
            if (rs.getInt(auth.getColumnName()) == 1)
                granted.add(auth);
        user.setAuthorities(granted);
        return user;
    }
}
```

The code to build the `List<GrantedAuthority> authorities` is now as simple as this:

```
List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
for (User_Authority auth : user.getAuthorities())
    authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(auth.getRoleName()));
```

As you can see, you now only have one place with 20 "repeats": The `enum` values.

If you need to add more later on, you of course add new column to user table and then you only need to add two items to the code:

- Add column to `SELECT` clause of SQL statement given to Spring JDBC Template.
- Add new `enum` value.

That is quite a simplification/improvement to the code, right?

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a List of class storing the relationship between the method and `SimpleGrantedAuthority`

```
public class RoleChecker
{
    Function<User, Integer> roleCheckFunction;
    SimpleGrantedAuthority theAuthority;

    public RoleChecker(Function<User, Integer> roleCheckFunction, SimpleGrantedAuthority theAuthority)
    {}
}
```

and execute the checking using loop.

```
List<RoleChecker> roles = new ArrayList<>();
roles.add(new RoleChecker(User::getBook_read, new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_BOOK_READ")));
roles.add(new RoleChecker(User::getBook_upd, new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_BOOK_UPD")));
// ....
for (RoleChecker check : roles)
{
    if (check.roleCheckFunction.apply(user) == 1)
        authorities.add(check.theAuthority);
}
```